# Golang complex regex with FindAllStringSubmatch

Tags: regex, go

I have a *superheroes* string, **all** of them have *name*s, but **not all** of them have attributes.

It has a format of `⛦name⛯attrName☾attrData☽`, where the `attrName☾attrData☽` is optional.

So, the *superheroes* string is:

`⛦superman⛯shirt☾blue☽⛦joker⛯⛦spiderman⛯age☾15yo☽girlFriend☾Cindy☽`

I want to use Regex to extract the string, and populates the result into a *slice of map*, as such:

```
[ {name: superman, shirt: blue},
  {name: joker},
  {name: spiderman, age: 15yo, girlFriend: Cindy} ]
```

I can't get it done in Go playground. I use the regex `⛦(\\w+)⛯(?:(\\w+)☾(\\w+)☽)*`, but it only can capture single attribute, i.e. regex unable to capture the `age` attributes.

My code is:

```
func main() {
    re := regexp.MustCompile("⛦(\\w+)⛯(?:(\\w+)☾(\\w+)☽)*")
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", re.FindAllStringSubmatch("⛦superman⛯shirt☾blue☽⛦joker⛯⛦spiderman⛯age☾15yo☽girlFriend☾Cindy☽", -1))
}
```

The Go Playground code is at here: https://play.golang.org/p/Epv66LVwuRK

The run result is:

```
[
    ["⛦superman⛯shirt☾blue☽" "superman" "shirt" "blue"]
    ["⛦joker⛯" "joker" "" ""]
    ["⛦spiderman⛯age☾15yo☽girlFriend☾Cindy☽" "spiderman" "girlFriend" "Cindy"]
]
```

The `age` is missing, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot capture arbitrary number of substrings with a single capturing group. You need to match the whole record first, and then match the subparts of it with another regex.

See an example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {

    str := "⛦superman⛯shirt☾blue☽⛦joker⛯⛦spiderman⛯age☾15yo☽girlFriend☾Cindy☽"

    re_main := regexp.MustCompile(`⛦(\w+)⛯((?:\w+☾\w+☽)*)`)
    re_aux := regexp.MustCompile(`(\w+)☾(\w+)☽`)
    for _, match := range re_main.FindAllStringSubmatch(str, -1) {
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", match[1])
        for _, match_aux := range re_aux.FindAllStringSubmatch(match[2], -1) {      
            fmt.Printf("%v: %v\n", match_aux[1], match_aux[2])
        }
        fmt.Println("--END OF MATCH--") 
    }  
}
```

See the [Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/1zaUSPujhAg)

Output:

```
superman
shirt: blue
--END OF MATCH--
joker
--END OF MATCH--
spiderman
age: 15yo
girlFriend: Cindy
--END OF MATCH--
```

Here, `⛦(\w+)⛯((?:\w+☾\w+☽)*)` is the main regex that matches and captures into Group 1 the main "key" and the string of the other key-values is captured into Group 2. Then, you need to iterate over the found matches, and collect all key-values from the Group 2 using `(\w+)☾(\w+)☽`.

Comment: Brilliant. I can't believe I've never thought of doing regex in two phases like this. TIL.

Answer (score 1):

You have set your `regex` like `⛦(\\w+)⛯(?:(\\w+)☾(\\w+)☽)*` which prints only two level of `key` and `value`, like it prints as per your `regex`:

```
[["⛦superman⛯shirt☾blue☽" "superman" "shirt" "blue"]
["⛦joker⛯" "joker" "" ""]
["⛦spiderman⛯age☾15yo☽girl☾Cindy☽" "spiderman" "girl" "Cindy"]]
```

I increase the regex one more `key` and `value` pairs and it prints the `age` value as well, follow the below code for `regex`:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile("⛦(\\w+)⛯(?:(\\w+)☾(\\w+)☽)*(?:(\\w+)☾(\\w+)☽)*")
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", re.FindAllStringSubmatch("⛦superman⛯shirt☾blue☽⛦joker⛯⛦spiderman⛯age☾15yo☽girl☾Cindy☽", -1))
```

Comment: but how about if it has more `(?:(\\w+)☾(\\w+)☽)`... then i need to add more pairs... I hope to have a solution that match **0 to N** pairs

Comment: sure, still I'm digging into it to be more valid solution for this.

Comment: I tried more but can't get success, you please go through this [link,](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html) may be you could find something.